# Unable to Get Response Header from Php PDO on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, http, pdo

I am trying to send back the last inserted id after I insert some data into my database.  I am successfully entering the data into the database, but there is no response data being sent back.  I am using Php PDO and it is hosted on Google App Engine and my headers are set to application/json in the dbconnect.php file.  What do I need to add to make it successfully send back response data.

```
<?php
    require('dbconnect.php');
    $statement=$con->prepare('INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname) VALUES (:fname,:lname)');
    $statement->execute(array(':fname' => $_POST['fname'], ':lname' => $_POST['lname'] ));
    $orderId = $statement->lastInsertId();
    $json = $json_encode($orderId);
    echo $json;
    $con = null;
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I got `Notice: Undefined index: fname` and `Notice: Undefined index: lname` and `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()`

Comment: There you go. You have no name attributes for the form elements you didn't post and make sure you're using a POST method for it too. In turn, more errors from PDO.

Comment: Add `name="lname"` and `name="fname"` for your form elements and you just may start seeing *magic* happen ;-)

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  It successfully inserts the data into the database.  I am using a POST method as well.  What do I need to do for the name attributes?  Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML form in your question.

Comment: Where do I add `name="lname"` and `name="fname"` ? Thanks

Comment: Again, post your HTML form in your question.

Comment: I posted an answer for you below, to better illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I got Notice: Undefined index: fname and Notice: Undefined index: lname and Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId() –  Moustache_Me_A_Question 10 mins ago*

You have no name attributes for the form elements.

Therefore you need to add them to your elements.

Here is an example form you can base yourself on:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="fname">
<br>
    Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lname">
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That is why you're getting undefined index notices.

---

`$json = $json_encode($orderId);` should read as `$json = json_encode($orderId);` - [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) shouldn't be a variable but the function itself.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Also:

```
$orderId = $statement->lastInsertId();
```

to

```
$orderId = $con->lastInsertId();
```

which is why you're getting this message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()

- lastInsertId() is a method of the PDO class, not the PDOStatement class.

which I found in Bill Karwin's answer when Googling the error:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580768/

Comment: I am sending a json object from AngularJS ` $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://example.com/postdata",
          data: $scope.formData
      })...` . And $scope.formData is `$scope.formData = {
          fname:$scope.user.firstName,
          lname:$scope.user.lastName};`

Comment: @Moustache_Me_A_Question Instead of `$orderId = $statement->lastInsertId();` try `$orderId = $con->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Once I changed `$json_encode(...)` to `json_encode(..)` it fixed the errors and I changed the header content-type from application/json to the default.  Thanks for your help @Fred -ii-

Comment: and you were right about the `$con->lastInsertId()` . Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh lordie of course. I should have spotted that lol @Moustache_Me_A_Question good catch on that :) Mind if I add that to my answer for others to see? and you're welcome.

Comment: @Moustache_Me_A_Question Would you like to mark it as solved? I've made a few edits in the answer for others to see, should they visit they question in the future.

Comment: I marked it as answered.  If I send a json object to my php script, how do I decode it.  I know i use `json_decode(...)` but what goes in the `...` ?

Comment: @Moustache_Me_A_Question To be perfectly honest with you, I only know a wee bit about json. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/19609354/ and this other Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/1270016/